# Logic of login into accounts using PHP and MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I need some advice on the best way of creating a login/account for my project.

here is what I am doing at the moment.

I register the users using a page called `register.php`. i get the users details and save them in mysql database. and I create a `subdomain` on my server for that user.

once the `subdomain` is created, I `copy` some files from one directory on my server into that subdomain. in those coppied files, I have `login` page which will ask the user to login so they can access their account( the account is that subdomain that was created for them when they registered).

so...

```
the user #1 created an account and given this URL: user1.mysite.com/login.php
```

and

```
the user #2 created an account and given this URL: user2.mysite.com/login.php
```

and once they logged in successfully, the will be directed to the `index.php` of their account which is **user1.mysite.com/index.php** or **user2.mysite.com/index.php** depending which user alogs in from which URL/account.

all of these work as they should.

**Now, here is the issue that I am facing:**

if the `user #1` tries to login from the `user #2` URL/account (*user2.mysite.com/login.php*), they will be pointed to their own URL/account which is (*user1.mysite.com/login.php*)...

**HOWEVER,**

if the same user (`user #1`) navigates back to the previous URL which was *user2.mysite.com/login.php*, they are automatically logged in to that account which doesn't belong to them and it belongs to user #2 even though they used their own login details!

***so basically, anyone can login to someone else's account!***

I am using `SESSION` in PHP for my login page. and I am using the following codes:

**Login Page:**

```
ob_start();
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["manager"])) {
    header("location: index.php"); 
    exit();
}


    if (isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {
           $manager =  $_POST["email"]; // filter everything but numbers and letters
            $password = (!empty($_POST['password'])) ? sha1($_POST['password']) : ''; // filter everything but numbers and letters
            $storenameTable = $_REQUEST['storeShop'];   

            // Connect to the MySQL database  
            include "config/connect.php";


            $sql = "SELECT members.id, members.email, members.password, members.randKey, members.storeShop, storename.email, storename.password, storename.randKey, storename.storeShop
                FROM members
                INNER JOIN storename ON members.randKey = storename.randKey
                WHERE members.email = '$manager'
                AND members.password = '$password'
            ";


        $result = mysqli_query($db_conx,"SELECT storeShop FROM members WHERE email='$manager' AND password='$password'");

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
          {
                $email = $row["email"];
                $password = $row["password"];
                $storeShop = $row["storeShop"];
                $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
                $_SESSION['storeShop'] = $storeShop;
          }

            // query the person
            // ------- MAKE SURE PERSON EXISTS IN DATABASE ---------
            $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
            if (!$query) {
                die(mysqli_error($db_conx));
            }
            $existCount = mysqli_num_rows($query); // count the row nums
            if ($existCount == 1) { // evaluate the count
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                $_SESSION["id"] = $row["id"];
                $_SESSION["manager"] = $manager;
                $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
                header("location: http://$storeShop.mysite.com/index.php");
                exit();
            } else {
                echo 'That information is incorrect, try again <a href="login">Click Here</a>';
                exit();
            }
        }


<form action="login.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="logform" id="logform" onsubmit="return validate_form ( );">
<div class="lock-holder">      
      <div class="form-group pull-left input-username">
               <div class="input-group">
                <input name="email" type="text" class="form-control " id="email"  value="email">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i><img src="images/membericon.png" width="22" height="20"></i></span>    
                </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group pull-right input-password">
               <div class="input-group">
                <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control " id="password" placeholder="************" >
```

**and my index.php**

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["manager"])) {
    header("location: login.php"); 
    exit();
}
// Be sure to check that this manager SESSION value is in fact in the database
    $managerID = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["id"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
    $manager =  $_POST["email"]; // filter everything but numbers and letters
    $password = (!empty($_POST['password'])) ? sha1($_POST['password']) : ''; // filter everything but numbers and letters
    $storenameTable = $_REQUEST['storeShop'];
// Run mySQL query to be sure that this person is an admin and that their password session var equals the database information
// Connect to the MySQL database  
include "config/connect.php";
    $sql = "SELECT members.id, members.email, members.password, members.randKey, members.storeShop, storename.email, storename.password, storename.randKey, storename.storeShop
        FROM members
        INNER JOIN storename ON members.randKey = storename.randKey
        WHERE members.email = '$manager'
        AND members.password = '$password'
    "; // query the person
// ------- MAKE SURE PERSON EXISTS IN DATABASE ---------
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    if (!$query) {
        die(mysqli_error($db_conx));
    }
$result = mysqli_query($db_conx,"SELECT storeShop FROM members WHERE email='$manager' AND password='$password'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
        $email = $row["email"];
        $password = $row["password"];
        $storeShop = $row["storeShop"];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
        $_SESSION['storeShop'] = $storeShop;
  }
$existCount = mysqli_num_rows($query); // count the row nums
if ($existCount == 0) { // evaluate the count
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
     header("location: login.php");
     exit();
}
}
```

could someone please advice on this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will probably create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Also, SHA1 hashing of a password without a salt is **terrible** and isn't even remotely secure.

Comment: @tadman, I will secure the code. this is not at the production stage at all.

Comment: @tadman, please don't be judgmental. This is my own personal project and i care about it alot more than anyone else and I know when and how to start doing stuff and at what stage! I appreciate what you're saying though. as for securing the code etc, I have been trying to do that for the past 3 days with other parts of it. so I will figure out the functionality first and then sort out the security etc...

Comment: I understand, but it's really *not hard* to do it properly. It's just a few more lines of code and you're 100% done. Using placeholders actually makes it easier to write code correctly because you won't have issues with inserting data that has `'`, or forgetting to properly quote strings. It's easier. It's better. It's not worth making excuses about it.

Comment: @tadman, i wish it was as easy as you say. it might be easy for you as an expert or someone who has alot of experience with PHP/MSQL. but not me mate. I've been trying to secure a login page (the same one that you see above) for almost 12 hours with no luck at all. I tried using prepared statement and bind param with no avail! but I will make sure it's secure before going live anyway. even if I have to pay someone to do for me. one of my sites was hacked years ago and not going to let that happen again.

Comment: The `prepare`, `bind`, `execute` triplet is not an insurmountable obstacle, it's really straightforward. See the examples [in the documentation](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). The object-oriented style of calling `mysqli` makes it especially easy to get right. Procedural mode you need to get the order of your arguments correct. You don't need to be an "expert" to write SQL code with placeholders. That's where you should start. Save the string interpolation for the experts because it's hard to get it right.

Comment: I was thinking once my code is working and secured, i might send it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for a review to make sure it really is secure before going live with it. so basically, I will make sure it is as secure as they come before attempting to use it.

Answer (score 0):

So basically any user can log into any user's account is that your main problem? You could compare the user name in the URL subdomain to the user name they have provided in the login form, if they dont match they get denied access.

Comment: As for back navigation you would have to compare the logged in user's username to the subdomain

Comment: Yes, that is the main problem. any chance you could provide an example ?

Answer (score 0):

In your login.php page put this

```
$url = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]; // not sure whether this gets the subdomain, try it
$user_subdomin = explode(".", $url);

if(isset($form_submitted)){
    if($user_subdomin[0] == $_POST["username"]){
        if($_POST["password"] == $password_from_db){ // where username equals form username
        // Set Sessions, do header redirect.
    }
    else print "You are in the wrong place!";
}
else // print form.
```

And on page's which requires the user to be logged in like index.php or admin.php or what ever put this:

```
$url = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]; // not sure whether this gets the subdomain, try it

$user_subdomin = explode(".", $url);

if($_SESSION["username"] != $user_subdomin){
    header("Location: ".$_SESSION["username"].".domin.com");
         // this take the user to the correct place
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately didn't make any difference! it either cannot get the subdomain or something else that i'm not aware of.

Comment: also, could you please explain your code some how? comment it or something as I'm not sure whats what!!

Comment: print $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] and tell me what it says

Comment: ah, it prints out the subdomain! so it does get the subdomain.

Comment: in what format? does it give you the full URL or just subdomain.domain.com?

Comment: just subdomain.domain.com

Comment: That's ok then. $user_subdomin = explode(".", $url); splits the URL by using . as the deliminator. Thats how we get the user's username from the URL by using $user_subdomain[0] because it gets split into an array. You said it's still not working?

Comment: in your first code, you said `// Set Sessions, do header redirect.`... where do I have to set the header redirect to? i.e. the login page or the index page?

Comment: also, what is `$form_submitted` ? I don't see it anywhere in my code or your code?

Comment: Sorry ive been away from my PC. $form_submitted is a form parameter which the if statement checks to see if the form has been submitted. When you've verified the user you'll want to set them a session so u can keep track of them so they don't need to login in all the time. The only way I can properly fix this is if u send me your login.php page and ill make the appropriate changes, then ill test it on my web server with static data to make sure it works. Obviously you'll be using data from your database but thats not a problem

Comment: My login.php code is in my question. the first code in my question is the exact code that I am using in my login.php file. the issue with your code is that, it has an infinite LOOP which in some browsers will eventually load the destination page (probably after 10 minutes) but in Firefox it will crash with an error stating that it cannot redirect due to infinite LOOP or whatever. please let me know if you need any other codes and I will send it to you.

Comment: It's a pain copying and pasting code in here. Zip up your index.php and login.php files including the forms and email me it if u want...

Comment: how can I find your email address mate?

Comment: I've sent you the email.

Comment: Ok I'll check it out now

Comment: When a user registers it creates a subdomain for them? What name is created for the subdomain?

Comment: yes, when the user is registered, a subdomain is created for them. they can choose a name for their subdomain. so it is a dynamic name so to speak.

Comment: Does the name of their subdomain go into their account in the database?

Comment: Yes, it will get stored in a column called `storeShop`.

Comment: I think im getting somewhere now. Is index.php located within their subdomain yeah?

Comment: Yes, index.php is in their subdomain.

Comment: Ok I've made changes with comments. I'm gonna zip the files back up and reply to your email

Comment: I've sent the new files.

Comment: Nope, Unfortunately that didn't work! here is what happens, I've changed the `rest_of_url` to `mysite.com` in the header location like so: `header("Location: ".$_SESSION["storeShop"].".mysite.com");` and when I run the code, I get this URL in the browser: `http://subdomain1.mysite.com/subdomain2.mysite.com`. basically it won't direct the user to their subdomain. it will add the session storeShop to the end of the URL. also, still everyone can login to eachother's account by just navigating back in their browsers.

Comment: I didn't know creating a simple login page can be so time consuming and a pain right in the back side!!!!!

Comment: I also tried this and I get that infinite LOOP issue: `header("location: http://$_SESSION[storeShop].mysite.com");`

Comment: does this look right to you: `header("Location: __DIR__.".$_SESSION["storeShop"].".mysite.com");`

Comment: your session variables might need debugging. Print your session vars on the web page and see whats getting put in them

Comment: I can print the session vars but it won't show anything before the user's logged in and once they are logged in then they will go to a URL that doesn't exist. so I cannot even see the printed session var's. I've sorted the navigation issue. I just need to know why the URL is weird.

Comment: it was like this: http://subdomain1.mysite.com/subdomain2.mysite.com.. but i sorted that out now as well... I now have another issue which is the infinite LOOK caused by the login page double header location. I explained it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23016305/this-webpage-has-a-redirect-loop-php-issue/23016481#23016481