# This webpage has a redirect loop PHP issue?

Tags: php

I am using the following codes in my `login.php` and `index.php` files.

I get the `This webpage has a redirect loop error` in the browser.

I know the issue is caused by the logic in the login.php file by the following code:

```
$existCount = mysqli_num_rows($query); // count the row nums
            if ($existCount == 1) { // evaluate the count
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                $_SESSION["id"] = $row["id"];
                $_SESSION["manager"] = $manager;
                $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
                header("location: http://$storeShop.mysite.com/index.php");
                exit();
            } else {
                echo 'That information is incorrect, try again <a href="login">Click Here</a>';
                exit();
            }
```

specifically this line: `header("location: http://$storeShop.mysite.com/index.php");`

I just do not know how I can fix this issue!

**LOGIN.PHP**

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();

if (isset($_SESSION["manager"])) {

    /*

    IF THE USER IS LOGGED IN THE CODE BELOW SENDS THEM TO THEIR OWN SUBDOMAIN NAME
    WHICH IS STORED IN $_SESSION["storeShop"].

    CHANGE "REST_OF_URL" TO THE VALID DOMAIN IN THE HEADER FUNCTION.
    BUT DON'T REMOVE THE . (DOT)

    */

    header("Location: http://$_SESSION[storeShop].mysite.com/index.php");
    exit();

    // END OF EDIT.
}

?>
<?php

    if (isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {
           $manager =  $_POST["email"]; // filter everything but numbers and letters
           $password = (!empty($_POST['password'])) ? sha1($_POST['password']) : ''; // filter everything but numbers and letters
            $storenameTable = $_REQUEST['storeShop'];   

            // Connect to the MySQL database  
            include "config/connect.php";


            $sql = "SELECT members.id, members.email, members.password, members.randKey, members.storeShop, storename.email, storename.password, storename.randKey, storename.storeShop
                FROM members
                INNER JOIN storename ON members.randKey = storename.randKey
                WHERE members.email = '$manager'
                AND members.password = '$password'
            ";


        $result = mysqli_query($db_conx,"SELECT storeShop FROM members WHERE email='$manager' AND password='$password'");

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
          {
                $email = $row["email"];
                $password = $row["password"];
                $storeShop = $row["storeShop"];
                $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
                $_SESSION['storeShop'] = $storeShop;
          }

            // query the person
            // ------- MAKE SURE PERSON EXISTS IN DATABASE ---------
            $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
            if (!$query) {
                die(mysqli_error($db_conx));
            }
            $existCount = mysqli_num_rows($query); // count the row nums
            if ($existCount == 1) { // evaluate the count
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                $_SESSION["id"] = $row["id"];
                $_SESSION["manager"] = $manager;
                $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
                header("location: http://$storeShop.mysite.com/index.php");
                exit();
            } else {
                echo 'That information is incorrect, try again <a href="login">Click Here</a>';
                exit();
            }
        }


?>
```

**INDEX.PHP**

```
<?php 
session_start();
ob_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION["manager"])) {
    header("location: login"); 
    exit();
}
/*

    THE CODE BELOW COMPARES THE SUBDOMAIN TO THE USER'S STORESHOP SESSION
    IF THEY DON'T MATCH IT REDIRECTS THEM TO THEIR SUBDOMAIN.

    CHANGE "REST_OF_URL" TO THE VALID DOMAIN IN THE HEADER FUNCTION.
    BUT DON'T REMOVE THE . (DOT)

    */
else {

    $url = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
    $user_subdomain = explode(".", $url);

    if($_SESSION["storeShop"] != $user_subdomain[0]) {
        header("Location: http://$_SESSION[storeShop].mysite.com/index.php");

    }
}
ob_end_flush();

// Be sure to check that this manager SESSION value is in fact in the database
    $managerID = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["id"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
    $manager =  $_POST["email"]; // filter everything but numbers and letters
    $password = (!empty($_POST['password'])) ? sha1($_POST['password']) : ''; // filter everything but numbers and letters
    $storenameTable = $_REQUEST['storeShop'];
// Run mySQL query to be sure that this person is an admin and that their password session var equals the database information
// Connect to the MySQL database  
include "config/connect.php";
    $sql = "SELECT members.id, members.email, members.password, members.randKey, members.storeShop, storename.email, storename.password, storename.randKey, storename.storeShop
        FROM members
        INNER JOIN storename ON members.randKey = storename.randKey
        WHERE members.email = '$manager'
        AND members.password = '$password'
    "; // query the person
// ------- MAKE SURE PERSON EXISTS IN DATABASE ---------
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    if (!$query) {
        die(mysqli_error($db_conx));
    }
$result = mysqli_query($db_conx,"SELECT storeShop FROM members WHERE email='$manager' AND password='$password'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
        $email = $row["email"];
        $password = $row["password"];
        $storeShop = $row["storeShop"];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
        $_SESSION['storeShop'] = $storeShop;
  }


?>
```

could someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's way too much for me to go through.  But I'm going to guess that at the end, your location ends up blank, which would redirect the page to the default for the server (index.php), which is itself, which is why you're getting a redirect loop.

Comment: where is `$storeShop` defined in your login.php? If it's undefined, then you're effectively doing `Location: .mysite.com`

Comment: @Marc, the `$storeShop` is stored in `mysql database` for the user `$manager`.

Comment: When i was login your app.... I redirected to the dashboard page than i refresh the page and i moved to login page it means your session value is not set. May be Yo are having some issue in your dashboard page. Please put the dashboard code here

Answer (score 0):

You're redirecting users to a different subdomain, and probably losing all your session data in the process.

Before you call `session_start()`, make sure your cookies are valid for the whole domain, i.e.,:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.mysite.com'); 
session_start();
```

[More information here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)

### Edit: Some other things you should look into:

(1) After the user has been redirected to "login" (`header("location: login");`), which of your scripts will process the next request? (Did you mean `login.php`?)

(2) What does `login.php` do when it receives a `GET` request (without an active session)?

Comment: I'm only redirecting the users to another subdomain if they try to login to someone else's account. so the first session is killed if they get redirected to another subdomain which is what I want. otherwise everyone could login to eachother's accounts.

Comment: @user3454730 I've edited my answer to add a couple more suggestions.

Comment: (1) Npt sure exactly what you mean. (2) it doesn't receive a GET without active sessions.

Answer (score 0):

You have started another session in index.php using session_start()

Remove the session_start() from index.php page and confirm if it is working fine